# Android onClickListener doesn't work for second time

Tags: java, android

When user clicks on button named calButton in my code (which has setOnClickListener method) for second time, it doesn't work and it just shows last results.
here's my code :

```
public void calculate(View view){
    //Identify IDs
    TextView delta = findViewById(R.id.delta);
    Button calButton = findViewById(R.id.calculatebtn);
    EditText textA = findViewById(R.id.editTextA);
    EditText textB = findViewById(R.id.editTextB);
    EditText textC = findViewById(R.id.editTextC);

    TextView root1 , root2;
    root1 = findViewById(R.id.root1);
    root2 = findViewById(R.id.root2);
    //Return text to float
    float a , b , c;
    a = Float.parseFloat(textA.getText().toString());
    b = Float.parseFloat(textB.getText().toString());
    c = Float.parseFloat(textC.getText().toString());
    //Calculate DELTA
    float deltaF = (b * b) - (4 * a * c);
    //Set Texts and Calculate Roots
    calButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        delta.setText("Delta : " + deltaF);
        delta.setAlpha(1);

        if (deltaF < 0) {
            root1.setText("Null");
            root1.setAlpha(1);
        } else if (deltaF == 0) {
            float root = -b / (2 * a);
            root1.setText("Root 1 : " + root);
            root1.setAlpha(1);
        } else if (deltaF > 0) {
            if (b > 0) {
                float bPosetive = (0.0f) - b;
                float root1F = (float) ((bPosetive + Math.sqrt(deltaF)) / (2 * a));
                float root2F = (float) ((bPosetive - Math.sqrt(deltaF)) / (2 * a));
                root1.setText("Root 1 : " + root1F);
                root2.setText("Root 2 : " + root2F);
                root1.setAlpha(1);
                root2.setAlpha(1);
            } else if (b < 0) {
                float bNegetive = (0.0f) - b;
                float root1F = (float) ((bNegetive + Math.sqrt(deltaF)) / (2 * a));
                float root2F = (float) ((bNegetive - Math.sqrt(deltaF)) / (2 * a));
                root1.setText("Root 1 : " + root1F);
                root2.setText("Root 2 : " + root2F);
                root1.setAlpha(1);
                root2.setAlpha(1);
            }
        }
    });


}
```

I expected that when user edits text and clicks on button for second time , it calculates inputs and show them , but doesn't work and just show last outputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `a`, `b`, `c` and `deltaF` is primitive type.
These values will not be changed when EditText values have changed.

Also, you shall separate your code logic into different methods. For this example, `calculate()` to calculate the value and `initUI()` to init the UI.

---

Code Examples

```java
public float calculate(float a, float b , float c) {
    return a + b + c;
}

public void initUI() {
    calButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
       EditText textA = findViewById(R.id.editTextA);
       EditText textB = findViewById(R.id.editTextB);
       EditText textC = findViewById(R.id.editTextC);

       float a , b , c;
       a = Float.parseFloat(textA.getText().toString());
       b = Float.parseFloat(textB.getText().toString());
       c = Float.parseFloat(textC.getText().toString());

       calculate(a, b, c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Beside decoupling, the difference between my and yours implementation is that when the onClick listener is triggered, it will get the `EditText` object value, assign to `primitive type` float and then pass to `calculate()` call